# Setting up a subdirectory in Apache

Tags: linux, apache-2.2, web-server

I have the following 2 files on my linux system:

**/var/www/index.html** = www.mywebsite.com

**/var/www/foo/bar/index.html** = www.mywebsite.com/foo/bar/index.html

I'm trying to figure out how I can set it up in Apache, so that when a user goes to "**www.mywebsite.com/somedirectory**" they are directed to the "**/var/www/foo/bar/index.html**" file.

So....

/var/www/index.html = www.mywebsite.com

/var/www/food/bar/index.html = www.mywebsite.com/somedirectory

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You should clarify your specific needs and current configuration, but the simple way to do this is via `mod_alias`:

```
Alias /somedirectory /var/www/foo/bar
```

If that doesn't work or you need different behavior or more sophisticated logic, then let us know.